# Rename node with xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am not that experienced with xml especially xslt translations but i simply want to rename a node within my xml.

My input xml is as follows;

```
<top>
    <output>
        <add>
          <add-attr attr-name="id">
            <value type="string">49824</value>
          </add-attr>
          <add-attr attr-name="uuid">
            <value type="string">9377c8d0-65c1-450a-9fdb-e67c851e90a8</value>
          </add-attr>
          <add-attr attr-name="username">
            <value type="string">0123460</value>
          </add-attr>
          <add-attr attr-name="firstname">
            <value type="string">Test</value>
          </add-attr>
          <add-attr attr-name="lastname">
            <value type="string">Tester6</value>
          </add-attr>
        </add>
    </output>
</top>
```

The `<add-attr>` node needs to be renamed to `<attr>` to produce the following output:

```
<top>
    <output>
        <add>
          <attr attr-name="id">
            <value type="string">49824</value>
          </attr>
          <attr attr-name="uuid">
            <value type="string">9377c8d0-65c1-450a-9fdb-e67c851e90a8</value>
          </attr>
          <attr attr-name="username">
            <value type="string">0123460</value>
          </attr>
          <attr attr-name="firstname">
            <value type="string">Test</value>
          </attr>
          <attr attr-name="lastname">
            <value type="string">Tester6</value>
          </attr>
        </add>
    </output>
</top>
```

I tried several xslt scenarios as example;

```
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//add-attr">
    <attr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </attr>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@add-attr">
    <xsl:attribute name="attr">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But up till now it does not provide any output.
Any idea where I  am failing?

The XSLT to be used has to be XSLT 1.0

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced using your (partial) code. That doesn't mean it's perfect code, but it should produce the expected result.

Comment: Assuming that the first line in your XSLT is `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">` (not included in what you posted), then the output should be what you are expecting. Is it possible that you aren't applying the XSLT that you think you are? Also, the match expression doesn't need the descendant axis. It could (and should) be `add-attr`, not `//add-attr`.

Comment: Are there any namspaces involved in the source-xml that are not in your example?

Comment: @michael.hor257k by checking my source xml; which has more data in it then shown in this example i noticed an extra line outside the xml and by testing i now noticed i was copying this extra line. This was the main reason the translation failed. So the translation did work allready, my failure to check twice. Nevertheless thanks for checking!

Comment: @MadsHansen yes see also my other comment. You're correct on this it works with both.

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed No there are no other namespaces involved but it works now. Anyway thanks for your comment.

Comment: @PetroHagenauw You should use a testing environment that provides error messages.